# I query to get a column default value but ORA-17003 appears

Tags: java, sql, oracle, swing

I need a method which returns a column default value, so I've made this method:

```
public String mostraDefault(String column) {
        String def = null; //default value
        try {
            //query to get the def value (tried on oracle and works)
            String sql = "Select DATA_DEFAULT from USER_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME ='CLASSDIAGRAM' and COLUMN_NAME = '" + column.toUpperCase() + "'";
            conn = Database.nuovaConnessione();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                def = rs.getString(1);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(ClassDiagram.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return def;
    }
```

This method is called by the following, which allows to insert recort into a table throughout a Java Swing GUI:

```
    public void insertRecord() {
        try {
            //query to insert
            String sql = "INSERT INTO ClassDiagram(Nome) VALUES(?)";
            conn = Database.nuovaConnessione();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            String nome;
            //handle default value
            if (txtNome.getText().isEmpty()) {
                //nome = "Nuovo progetto";
                nome = mostraDefault("nome");
                System.out.println(nome); //this correctly prints its def val on stout
            } else {
                nome = txtNome.getText();
            }
            ps.setString(1, nome);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //this gets thrown
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage(), "Errore SQL: " + e.getErrorCode(),
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage(), "Errore",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } 
    }
```

But this method throws

> Errore SQL 17003: invalid column index

(SQLException gets thrown)

But I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Edit: if I close rs and conn in a finally clause in `mostraDefault` method,

> Errore SQL 17009: closed statement
>   gets thrown.

Comment: Are you intentionally not closing `rs`, `ps` and `conn` in `mostraDefault`? It looks like `Database.nuovaConnessione()§ is probably giving you the *same* connection object from both calls, is that correct?

Comment: If i close that resources, another exception is thrown: 17009 closed statement

Comment: Yes, or use try-with blocks; otherwise you'll leak connections at some point. That's only part of the problem though, if the same connection is used for both.

Comment: 17009 closed statement is thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues really. Firstly you aren't closing the result set, statement or connection in your `mostraDefault` method, or the statement or connection in your  `insertRecord` method. (You might want to investigate try-with blocks so you don't have to do that explicitly).

You are then getting the same connection object from both calls to `Database.nuovaConnessione()`. At the moment that means that the inner call to `mostraDefault` is relplacing the statement you already parsed, so when you come bind a value the statement no longer has a bind placeholder. Once you've closed the connection in `mostraDefault` the bind will instead see that the connection it thinks it has is already closed.

The fix for that part is simple: get the default value earlier:

```
    public void insertRecord() {
        try {
            String nome;
            //handle default value
            if (txtNome.getText().isEmpty()) {
                //nome = "Nuovo progetto";
                nome = mostraDefault("nome");
                System.out.println(nome); //this correctly prints its def val on stout
            } else {
                nome = txtNome.getText();
            }

            //query to insert
            String sql = "INSERT INTO ClassDiagram(Nome) VALUES(?)";
            conn = Database.nuovaConnessione();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, nome);
            ps.executeUpdate();
...
```

Then the two DB calls won't overlap at all.

But, again, look into try-with blocks, if you're on a suitable version of Oracle (and if Spring is happy with those, no idea...)

Comment: I actually closed that object in a finally clause of insert method but accidentally cut when pasting the code here. This actually worked but for some reason this gets the default value with ' ' (for example 'Nuovo progetto' instead of Nuovo Progetto) but i fixed this. Thanks

Comment: The quotes are included in `data_default`, so you probably need to trim them off yourself if you want to use that data dictionary value like this.